# Construction of Galois group of infinite extension

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be Galois. I am trying to understand the construction of the Galois group for $K/F$ using inverse limits. To do this, we consider those fields $L$ such that $F\subset L\subset K$ and $L/F$ is finite and Galois. For intermediary fields $L$ we get a poset by inclusion (and, in fact, a directed set). Whenever $L_1\subset L_2$ we have the restriction map Gal$(L_2/F)\rightarrow$ Gal$(L_1/d)$ and so it makes sense to talk about the inverse limit.

Now, Gal$(K/F)$ is defined to be $\lim_L$Gal(L/F)$ where the inverse limit is taken over the directed set described above. However, since there may be multiple chains in this poset, does is matter which one we choose in the inverse limit? There may be no particular inclusion relation between two particular subfields, so I'm not sure what it would mean to take the inverse limit over all these fields.

Comment: Tamas Szamuely's Galois Groups and the Fundamental Group has a very well written construction of the infinite Galois extension. I would check it out.

Comment: The restriction map is a projection (quotient) map and it is a projective limit. You should look at $F = \Bbb{Q},K = \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty}), Gal(K/F) = \varprojlim  Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})/\Bbb{Q})= \varprojlim \Bbb{Z/p^n Z}^\times = \Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ because it works the same way in the general case. You need to take any tower $\ldots/F_{m+1}/F_m/\ldots/F$ such that $F_m/F$ is Galois and any finite Galois subextension of $K/F$ is contained in some $F_m$ then $Gal(K/F) = \varprojlim Gal(F_m/F)$

Comment: @reuns So any tower suffices? If so, then that answers my questions.

Comment: I must say for uncountable fields like $\Bbb{\overline{C(x)}/C(x)}$ the tower needs to be indexed by transfinite indices (thus the Zorn lemma / axiom of choice stuffs)